# Adding images in html page using c++ file handling

Tags: html, c++, file-handling

I have created one html file using ofstream in c++. I have one folder in my system and in that I have 10 jpeg images.
Now I want to add that 10 images to my html page using loop.
I have add one image in my html page.
My question is how to add 10 jpeg images which are in same folder but having different names using one loop?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

     ifstream folder;
     ofstream myfile;
     char buffer[500]={'0'};

     folder.open("/home/tanmay/exp");

     myfile.open ("MY_FILE.html");

     myfile << "<!DOCTYPE html>"<<endl;

     sprintf(buffer,"00_FrontView.jpg");

     myfile<<"<table align=""center"" border=""2""width=""600"" height=""50"">"

           <<"<td><center><a href="<<"\""<<buffer<<"\""<<"target=""_self"">" 

           <<"<img src="<<"\""<<buffer<<"\""<<"width=""150"" height=""100""/>"

           <<"</center></td>"<<endl;

     myfile << "</table></body></html>";

     myfile.close();
     folder.close();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't `open` folders. And `char buffer[500]={'0'};` is probably not what you meant. Use the standard library, no c-style arrays, use experimental or boost filesystem libraries. Yeah, and the loop you were talking about. That's all.

Comment: Either you have to use platform-specific functions to get the contents of a directory. Or if your compiler is new enough you can use the upcoming C++17 [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library (or its "inspiration" [Boost fileystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)).

Comment: Can anyone give me one example regarding filesystem library or boost filesystem libraries?